# Pod Integration for google Plus and Google AppInvite together in app

Tags: ios, google-plus, cocoapods, google-app-invites

I'm Doing Login with GPP in my Application used latest GPP pod as pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk', Now I want Google App invite in my application.
For That I added first pod 'Google/SignIn', Which is working fine.
But once I add pod 'Google/AppInvite' it generates duplicate files error with GPP framewok.

Is there any way by with i can have both frameworks in my app i.e
'google-plus-ios-sdk' and 'Google/AppInvite'

Thanks
Ashwin.

Comment: why don't you just  use  pod 'Google' ?

Comment: @Muhammad, I Can't remove GPP, I have requested the client to go with google only...But he will need access on GPP as well. So there must be a way to use GPP and google/appinvite.  :)

Comment: pod google includes all google services. There will be no duplication .

Comment: @Muhammad, I need GPPSignIn as well. ;(

Comment: As per the google documents G+ is deprecated..

Comment: @AshwinKanjariya Have you solve this issue in the mean time? I have the same problem. I'm using the pods "GoogleMaps", "Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK", "Google/Analytics" and "Google/AppInvite" and get all the duplicate symbol errors. Somehow, they are in conflict with each other.

Comment: @Codo, Yes Let me post answer in a min

Answer (score 1):

I have update my pod file as

target 'MyAppTarget' do

```
#pod 'google-plus-ios-sdk'
pod 'Google/AppInvite'
pod 'Google/SignIn'
```

end

I have commented the google-plus-ios-sdk pod file and then checked the google plus login.... and I'm logged in at GPP by getting same details like id, email etc in GIDGoogleUser object.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, it doesn't work in my case. I have many more pods (incl. GoogleMaps, Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK, Google/Analytics) that I cannot remove.

Comment: @Codo, I have many pods too... like FB sdks and all... But for google app invite and GPP login.. Its manage for above tow pods.